# Reduce load average on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, cpu, cpu-load

How to I reduce the average CPU load on Ubuntu 14.04? I have a low end PC and whenever I start Google Chrome the load average is at ~2,5-3

My Computer Specifications are:

- Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU 430 @ 1.80GHz. One core
- 4GB RAM

Comment: I wouldn't say CPU load of 2.5 percent is high. Why do you think you need to reduce it?

Comment: firefox tends to use less CPU than chrome in my experience

Comment: @ScottStensland I need it for debug tools.

Comment: @mikewhatever I thought 1 or less it's optimal. And I thought problem was only with cpu, because RAM is using for half. All system works with freezing.

Comment: disable unused extensions and minimize number of tabs ...  for code dev purposes I would spring for a kickup to 8 gig of RAM if possible ... especially if the system is tipping into using Swap ... high CPU often indicates the OS is thrashing trying to swap in/out

Comment: @ScottStensland recize swap partition with more space, it's good idea or it will not help?

Comment: @Baterson Well, half is 50%, which is way more (20 times) then 2.5%. I really don't think you need to worry about CPU or RAM or swap. I do think, the graphics card may need checking. Can you add the output of `lspci -nnk` to the question. In case you can't edit questions, please use http://pasebin.com to post outputs.

Comment: @Baterson More swap likely wouldn't help unless you are using all of your swap-memory already. For example, if you are using 1GB of 2GBs of swap, re-sizing to 3GBs wouldn't improve speed. Swap is limited by the speed of the SSD/HDD it is partitioned on and since non-volatile memory is slower than volatile memory (RAM), using swap is inherently slow to begin with and your best off not using swap at all if you can help it.

Comment: @mikewhatever You may to on to something, Chrome uses graphics acceleration whenever possible and that could be causing these issues.

Comment: @mikewhatever I think you dont understand me,  my CPU load by 80% when I just loading page, load average is ~2,5-3. Here is `lspci -nnk` http://pastebin.com/0Czy5j2n

Comment: @Baterson You may want to revise the question, and post all that info, including the graphics, CPU usage and freezes. May be, when you add it, I'll understand better. Meanwhile, I've been trying to work with the info you provided, without imagining things.

Comment: @mikewhatever sorry, I can add more info if it helps